# To HashMap or not to HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to create some code that will read information off of a text file. For example `Bus_Routes.txt`will contain `Route_A.txt 283,284` and from that the file `Route_A.txt` is opened and it contains 2 columns, `Latitude Longitude` with the coordinates listed. This I wrote out fine.

From this I am trying to get the device with id 283 to travel along the coordinates in sequence. I was recommended to use a HashMap. So my plan is to create a HashMap for the coordinates of `Route_A.txt`, have one column for `Latitude` and the other for `Longitude`. From that I was going to create another HashMap that will contain the device_id and the HashMap containing the coordinates, and the device_id will travel through each step of the HashMap.

Can this be done or am I completely looking in the wrong area?
If anyone has any suggestions out there, they would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store your coordinates in a `HashMap`. It would be difficult to store multiple coordinates with the key (latitude?) being the same. e.g.  a simple `Map<Integer, Integer>` would only hold one longitude value for a latitude, and that would prevent your route from having multiple destinations along the same longitude line.

I would rather use:

```
List<Coord>
```

where `Coord` is your lat/long pair. The `List` will preserve order, whereas a normal `HashMap` wouldn't.

Note that I'm deliberately encapsulating the lat/long pair as a specific object. You could store it as a tuple of integers but I'd rather a specific object to enforce typing, permitting addition of functionality etc. As noted elsewhere, Java is an OO language and you shouldn't shy from creating classes to represent these concepts (a sign that you should do this is when you create something like `Map<String,List<Integer,Integer>>`)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. So you are suggesting I create a separate class to get the coordinates, that will contain getters and setters (right?), if you haven't gathered I'm rather new to this! From that I call the getSet class and make the `List<Coord>`?

Comment: I would expect Coord to contain your lat/long points (and possibly your setters/getters - perhaps you won't need setters since you'll just set the members in your constructor?)

Answer (score 2):

A HashMap is a data structure that let's you associate a value with a key, and allows, given a key, to get back the value in constant time (without the need to loop as you would have to with a list or an array, for example).

So use this structure if your usecase needs such a functionality. Having devices stored in a map, where the device ID is the key, sounds like a good idea.

If, on the other hand, you want a data structure to contain fields (like latitude, longitude), then create a class. Java is an OO language. You should create your own classes. And if you want a list of coordinates, then you should use a `List<Coordinate>`, and not a HashMap.